# Best way to get element from array

Tags: swift

What is the elegant way to get id from array ? 
For example I get this JSON from API that give name and ID

```
{
    "objectX": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Test"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Test 2"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

First I get name, then I set in picker, then I get the option that user chose but at the end I have to get id to send API request
Currently I get data from API and set in array (channels), then I iterate array and if channel name its equals I return the id

```
  func getID(channelName:String)->Int{ // channelName comes from textField
    var idChannel = 0
    for item in self.channels{
      if channelName == item.name{
        idChannel = item.id
      }
    }
    return idChannel
  }
```

Comment: Don't you get the index (row) in the array that the user has selected?

Answer (score 0):

## There's an easier way

Swift has a nice function to find what you're looking for. However, there are no guarantees that it will find it. I would change your function to look like this:

```swift
func getID(channelName: String ) -> Int? {
    channels.first(where: { $0.name == channelName })?.id 
}
```

Comment: You'll want to return an optional or provide a fallback value.

Comment: Also, this could be problematic if there are multiple elements in the array with the same channel name. Ideally, I'd use a set to articulate this instead.